# Element Click Intercepted Exception: The second drop down values are not getting selected

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have added waits also tried with explicit wait with visibility of element and also not visibility of element but still the element is not clickable.

In the Code that I have written it clicks on the second drop down but does not select the value .

Below is the Code:

```
        elementutils.waitforElementPresent(addbutton);

        elementutils.doclick(addbutton);

        Thread.sleep(5500);

        elementutils.doclick(selectfieldsdropdownclick1);

        elementutils.waitforElementnotvisible(selectfieldsvalueselection, driver);

        elementutils.multiselectdropdown(selectfieldsvalueselection, fieldvalue);
```

**Exception**: `Element Click Intercepted`

Comment: Why are you using thread sleep and webdriver wait both ?

can you share URL here ?

Comment: i have tried both the options not using both  https://ui.cogmento.com/deals need to click on pipeline in the page

Comment: any suggestions

Comment: At which line of code its failing.

Comment: elementutils.multiselectdropdown(selectfieldsvalueselection, fieldvalue); last line

Comment: @sandy: Can you add page HTML and locator your using in code?

Comment: this is the locator for selecting the value from the dropdown://div[@class='visible menu transition']/div/span                                                                                                                               and this is locator for selecting the drop down 1=//div[@class='visible menu transition']/div/span   and for dropdown 2  = //div[@class='visible menu transition']/div/span

Comment: this is the html -<div class="visible menu transition"><div role="option" aria-checked="false" aria-selected="true" class="selected item" style="pointer-events: all;"><span class="text">Probability</span></div><div role="option" aria-checked="false" aria-selected="false" class="item" style="pointer-events: all;"><span class="text">Amount</span></div><div role="option" aria-checked="false" aria-

Comment: any suggestions

Comment: any inputs by someone